# How to have the same dependencies in subprojects without repeating yourself?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android project, set up with gradle, consisting of:

1.) Two subprojects ( Android Studio modules that build slightly different apps), with their own build.gradle files.

and

2.) one "library project" with shared, common code.

Currently, the "dependencies" block of the build.gradle files for the two subprojects have a bunch of the same lines ( violating the "don't repeat yourself" principle.):

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation rootProject.ext.timber
    implementation rootProject.ext.glide
    ....
}
```

Those lines are referencing definitions in a file "dependencies.gradle" in the root dir of the project setup.

```
ext {
    timber = 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.0'
    glide = 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    ....
}
```

(The list of "implemenation foo" lines is much longer that in this example.)

Now my question:
What's the best way to define these dependencies in one place? Or, what's the best approach to avoid having to repeat these all over the place (e.g. if I have more than just two modules sharing some of the same dependencies).

Comment: to clarify: I'm looking for a way to replace a series of "implemenation xyz" statements with one function call or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share project configuration by having the root build apply the common steps to the different projects.

Either with:

```
allprojects {
    // Shared config for ALL projects goes here
}
```

or with:

```
subprojects {
    // Shared config for ALL child projects
}
```

And so in your case, you would have:

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        ....
        implementation rootProject.ext.timber
        implementation rootProject.ext.glide
        ....
    }
}
```

In addition to these methods, you can use the `configure()` method which takes a list of project as arguments and will configure only those. And you can use any filtering system you like to get that list of projects.

For more information, see the [documentation on authoring multi project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

Comment: That's an interesting way to do this. What I don't love about this approach is that it looks like I can't pick from the subprojects ( app projects in my case ) which "groups" to include. Or could I do that somehow by adding properties to some subprojects, and then conditional logic in the root script? Either way, ideally, it would be great to be able to "pick and choose" from the sub modules which "groups" to use.

Comment: I have edited my answer to mention the `configure()` method taking a list of projects.

Comment: Thanks! So now I could define properties on the subprojects, and based on those, configure them as I wish.

Comment: If that answers your question, please accept the answer then :-)

Answer (score 2):

I kind of understand what you’re asking but… what is the point of “common, shared code” if you aren’t sharing, for example, Glide? :) 
In truth, if you’re using Gradle 3.+ then you have to change `implementation` with `api`

So, in your common library/code:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    api rootProject.ext.timber
    api rootProject.ext.glide
    ....
}
```

If you want to learn more about this, check [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration) for a gradle migration (where they introduced all these new things).

You will find out that:

1. `implementation 'example.dependency:1.0.0’` --> only used within this module.
2. `api 'example.dependency:1.0.0’` --> also available in any builds that depend on the module.

Comment: I have to agree that this works for my situation, and seems to be a practical approach, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution, especially after reading the docs here (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations ) ... Sounds like using "api" has some downsides, e.g. in terms of build times.

Comment: re: sharing Glide — It's just an example ;-). My question was intended to be a general one: Let's say I have some groups of "implementation" statements that I want to share between modules of the same build, shouldn't there be a way to do that?

Comment: @treesAreEverywhere the solution is `api` in your shared/common module. It’s the equivalent of the old `compile` and it’s the recommended approach. The downside in terms of “build times” would still be present in any other form, because the “longer build time” comes from the fact that if you update a library, the dependency tree has to be updated for everyone depending on it as well, this is not a problem of `api`, but a problem that exists in all package dependency trees.

Comment: Saved my life, for more details: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation